# C++ variadic template - limit number of args

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template class with set function, that fills interal array:

```
template <size_t Dim>
class Vector
{
public:

    void SetValueTemplate(size_t index)
    {
        return;
    }

    template <typename X0, typename ...Xn>
    void SetValueTemplate(size_t index, X0 x0, Xn... xn)
    {
        val[index] = x0;
        SetCenterValueTemplate(index + 1, xn...);
    }

    template <typename ...X0>
    void SetValue(X0... t0)
    {
        SetValueTemplate(0, t0...);
    }

private:
    double val[Dim];
};
```

Problem is, that I can call this

```
Vector<3> v;
v.SetValue(0, 1, 2, 4, 5);
```

and it compiles correctly. Can I limit this to not compile? I can use `static_assert`, but is it possible without it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, without `static_assert`. For example, let's assume we want our `vector` class to only be assignable with the name number of arguments as the dimension of the vector, you can use:

```
template<std::size_t Dim>
struct vector {
    template <typename X0, typename ...Xn>
    typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Xn) + 1 == Dim, void>::type
    assign(X0 x0, Xn... xn) {}
};
```

This just uses `std::enable_if` in combination with `sizeof...` to enable or disable the specific assign function.

So the following will compile:

```
vector<3> x;
x.assign(1, 2, 3);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69da523eb4f1134a)

but this won't:

```
vector<3> x;
x.assign(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9823740f232fafab)

with (for Clang):

```
main.cpp:14:7: error: no matching member function for call to 'assign'
    x.assign(1, 2, 3, 4);
    ~~^~~~~~
```

and neither will this:

```
vector<3> x;
x.assign(1, 2);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b2263cbdfc7317e)

with a similar error message.

Comment: This wont compile with MSVC 2013 - `'type' : is not a member of 'std::enable_if<false,void>'`

Comment: @MartinPerry Can you show me exactly the code that doesn't compile? For `std::enable_if<false, void>` there indeed no `type` member. That is the error that should appear in the second case.

Comment: If I put it inside that "live demo" page, it compiles correctly. Seems like MSVC2013 issue

Comment: @melak47 In that case I can ranther use static_assert

Comment: It appears that for some reason, `assign` is being instantiated with `sizeof...(Xn) == 1` even without us calling it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a49ccfa69dc3074e

Comment: Works with MSVC++14.0(2015).

Comment: I can see it is working but I am not sure why. why are we using `vector<3>` instead of `vector<3*sizeof(int)>` ? Does `sizeof...(Xn) + 1 == Dim` evaluate as `sizeof (...(Xn) + 1) == Dim` ?

Comment: It works because [sizeof...](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...) returns the number of elements in a parameter pack.